# Creating AD user with powershell

Tags: configuration, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been looking around the web for a whole day, but didn't found a clue.

My problem is that I want to create Active Directory users via powershell. I've been doing good so far, but I must set in the property dial-in tab, the remote access permission option to "Allow Access", but I don't know how.

Do anyone have a clue or a trick to do so?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Attribute : [msNPAllowDialin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

True : Allowed

False : Denied

Not-Defined : Control by policy